# Python Pandas DataFrame; Place to excel cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**Hello, I want to put each "0" in excel cells. How can I do this?**

This is my python code for convert json to Dataframe and to excel

```html
with urllib.request.urlopen(myurl.json") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df1 = df.stack().swaplevel()
```

And this is the output image.

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL4Fw.png)

This is how I want to do

[Image, how ı want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXViz.png)

And this is my json file

```html
{"ADMİN":{"MUSTAFA SEMİH YAMAN":[null,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]}}
```

Comment: Do you want zeros to be used as column names?

Comment: @prajwalkumar No, it should be in cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there will always be only one key/value pair, the following piece of code should work.

```
data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
role = list(data.keys())[0]
name = list(data[role].keys())[0]
listData = data[role][name]
columns = ['', '']+list(range(0, len(listData)))

df = pd.DataFrame([role, name]+listData).T #transform the dataframe
df.columns = columns
df.to_csv("result.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: There will be 0's and 1's in json. There are no 1's on the current json. I'm editing the question. Sorry.

Comment: @msy still the above code snippet should work. Please upvote it if helps

Comment: what is the key in df = pd.DataFrame([key, name]+list).T ?

Comment: Okay that's worked but ı have one more question. How I start the column name (0,1,2..) from 0's and 1's (after MUSTAFA SEMİH YAMAN) ? With this code starts from start point pf table.